# Add elements of a list to all elements in certain columns

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Here my "problem":
Given a numpy array as

```
array([[4, 3, 5, 1],
       [2, 3, 3, 4],
       [4, 2, 2, 7]])
```

what I would like to do now is use a list of values

```
values = [3, 2]
```

and add them to all elements of certain columns, e.g. columns 2 and 3 leading to

```
new_array([[4,6,7,1],
           [2,6,5,4],
           [4,5,4,7]])
```

How can that be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = np.array([[4, 3, 5, 1],
       [2, 3, 3, 4],
       [4, 2, 2, 7]])

values = [3, 2]

a[:,(1,2)] += values

print(a)
```

Prints:

```
[[4 6 7 1]
 [2 6 5 4]
 [4 5 4 7]]
```

Comment: awesome. thank you. I have seen that you used a tuple. What if I have a list that consists of n-1 values whereas my array has n columns? is it possible to just add x,y,z, via commata in the bracket?

Comment: @Dorian, what does "just add x,y,z via comma in bracket" mean?

Comment: a[:,(1,2,3,4,...)] - so adding more than 2 values of a list. is that possible?